# Plotting just one branch of hyperbolas

Tags: plotting

I have a family of hyperbolas that I want to plot. Right now, I have this code

```
r[θ_, a_, e_, θ0_] := (a (1 - e^2))/(1 + e Cos[θ - θ0])
Module[{a = -1, e = 2},
PolarPlot[Evaluate@Table[r[θ, a, e, θ0], {θ0, 0/180 π, 40/180 π, 20/180 π}], {θ, 0, 2 π},
Exclusions -> Table[Cos[θ - θ0] == -(1/e), {θ0, 0/180 π, 40/180 π, 20/180 π}],
PlotRange -> 4]]
```

which produces this:

[image: Family of hyperbolas]

I'd like to keep only the left side branches (the ones for which the focus is at the origin). Is this possible?

Note: One possible way I can think of doing this is to calculate each hyperbola asymptote angle, plot each one separately for $\theta$ a range that only encompasses the desired branch, and merge it all in a final plot. However, I was wondering if it's possible to do it all in one go, in the same plot. Possibly, in a more elegant way rather than just brute forcing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ConditionalExpression`:

```
r[θ_, a_, e_, θ0_] := 
  With[{c = Cos[θ - θ0]}, 
   ConditionalExpression[(a (1 - e^2))/(1 + e c), c > -1/e]];
Module[{a = -1, e = 2}, 
 PolarPlot[
  Evaluate@Table[
    r[θ, a, e, θ0], {θ0, 0/180 π, 40/180 π, 20/180 π}],
  {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
  Exclusions -> 
   Table[Cos[θ - θ0] == -(1/e),
     {θ0, 0/180 π, 40/180 π, 20/180 π}], PlotRange -> 4]]
```

[image]

I think you can omit the `Exclusions`, if they were an attempt to deal with the branches.  Then you won't get the gaps at the ends of the green and gold curves.

Comment: Simple and elegant, just what I was looking for. And yes, I used `Exclusions` for that purpose, but it seems it won't be needed anymore.